# NanoHttpd : Android : Socket - java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)

Tags: android, sockets, nanohttpd

I am new to NanoHttpd. I am using this to stream a video in Android. For just normal playing this works like a charm without any issue. But when I try to seek to different time in the VideoPlayer, immediatly I get the following error and it creates a different socket and resumes to play after some time. But it shows the progress indicator for long time, which I think because of this issue and re-connecting with different socket. And Streaming is from local network server.

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:546)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:515)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1423)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1396)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1386)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1371)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:794)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:195)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
        at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:206)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:513)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1423)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1396)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1386)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1371)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:794)
        at me.etrmntonwheels.surfacetest.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:195)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am using serveFile function from SimpleWebServer sample to achieve partial content or streaming. I have read different articles and googled through stackoverflow but still could not figure out the reason.I am stuck at this issue from long time. Please help me to resolve this issue.

You can find the simpleWebServer file at https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/webserver/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/SimpleWebServer.java

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? I'm in the same situation.